# In dexie.js how can I obtain all records from a table?

Tags: javascript, dexie

In dexie.js, is there a way to obtain all records from a table?

Currently I am using:

```
dbTable.filter(() => true).then( ... )
```

It works but I am not sure, whether it's the right way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```js
db.table("tableName").toArray().then( ... )
```

Answer (score 8):

you can try this

```
const all = await db.friends.toArray()
```